# Extract multiple sequences from fasta but with different name

Tags: python, biopython

I am trying to extract a subset of sequences from a fasta file based on ID list, so far so good. 
My issue is that my ID list contains an extra column two (which represents the coding part of the sequence) and I want to keep that in the new fasta file

```
File 1: Id list
>TCONS_00000004  654:819
>TCONS_00000006  238:367
>TCONS_00000009  956:1555

File 2: fasta file
>TCONS_00000004
AAAATAATAAACTTTGCAAAGAGCAAATTTGAAGAAGCAGTTGATATACGTCGAGAGATTTCTGCAACAG 
CGCGATTATATTACATTCAATTAATTAAAATGCAGTACAGAGACATCCACGATTTCGTCAACATACCAGG
>TCONS_00000006
AAAATAATAAACTTTGCAAAGAGCAAATTTGAAGAAGCAGTTGATATACGTCGAGAGATTTCTGCAACAG 
CGCGATTATATTACATTCAATTAATTAAAATGCAGTACAGAGACATCCACGATTTCGTCAACATACCAGG
>TCONS_00000009
AAAATAATAAACTTTGCAAAGAGCAAATTTGAAGAAGCAGTTGATATACGTCGAGAGATTTCTGCAACAG 
CGCGATTATATTACATTCAATTAATTAAAATGCAGTACAGAGACATCCACGATTTCGTCAACATACCAGG

Expected outcome:
 >TCONS_00000004 654:819
AAAATAATAAACTTTGCAAAGAGCAAATTTGAAGAAGCAGTTGATATACGTCGAGAGATTTCTGCAACAG 
CGCGATTATATTACATTCAATTAATTAAAATGCAGTACAGAGACATCCACGATTTCGTCAACATACCAGG
>TCONS_00000006 238:367
AAAATAATAAACTTTGCAAAGAGCAAATTTGAAGAAGCAGTTGATATACGTCGAGAGATTTCTGCAACAG 
CGCGATTATATTACATTCAATTAATTAAAATGCAGTACAGAGACATCCACGATTTCGTCAACATACCAGG
>TCONS_00000009 956:1555
AAAATAATAAACTTTGCAAAGAGCAAATTTGAAGAAGCAGTTGATATACGTCGAGAGATTTCTGCAACAG 
CGCGATTATATTACATTCAATTAATTAAAATGCAGTACAGAGACATCCACGATTTCGTCAACATACCAGG
```

I tried with the following biopython commands but it will only extract from file2 without the additional numbers that I need.

```
from Bio import SeqIO
id = []
for line in open("test.txt","r"):
    id.append(line.rstrip().strip('\t'))
for rec in SeqIO.parse("mymodified_transcript.fa","fasta"):
    if rec.id in id:
        print rec.format("fasta")
```

How can I keep the additional numbers and also extract the sequences from file2? Or replace the name in the file 2 by the ones in file 1?
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution. It worked fine in my Ubuntu. Please try this :)

```
from Bio import SeqIO
temp = {}
for line in open("test.txt","r"):
    i, c = line.strip().split()
    temp[i] = c

for rec in SeqIO.parse("mymodified_transcript.fa","fasta"):
    if str('>'+rec.id) in temp.keys():
        print str('>'+rec.id), temp['>'+rec.id]
        print str(rec.seq)
```

Comment: Please don't use id as this is really confusing and not a good practice as you are working with rec.id and comparing with a list/dict with the same name called id. Moreover, when you are working with list/dict, you are unconsciously missing the starting '>' in case of comparison. Hope, the solution helps!

Comment: Awesome. I am really glad that it worked. Please accept the answer that would be my greatest gift on this Friday night :)

Cheers!

Comment: Helped a lot and thanks for the advice,always nice to have some because I am just starting biopython, thanks again

Comment: No worries. I didn't work with BioPython during the last one year or so but spent few years with this, really a great library indeed! No problem, man.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a dictionary for the id lookup rather than a list? For e.g.

```
from Bio import SeqIO
id = {}
for line in open("test.txt","r"):
    i, c = line.strip().split()
    id[i] = c
for rec in SeqIO.parse("mymodified_transcript.fa","fasta"):
    if rec.id in id:
        print rec.id, id[rec.id]
        print rec.format("fasta")
```

Comment: this is a good idea and I tried it before but it is not working either, I get nothing!

Comment: What does text.txt contain? What happens if you mention the filename of the id list?

Comment: text.txt is the file with id list

Comment: Does the file contain only one column or both? If it is both then how does the id match in Line 6 of your code?

Comment: The code I wrote only works if I remove the second column (yes my file contains two columns) I don't know how to do it!

Comment: Well, my code works only if test.txt contains the second column :)

Comment: But how can you match the length with the right sequence in the fasta file?

Comment: Looks like I missed adding the '<' character. Happy that the other answer worked for you.